# Assume ownership of git changes introduced by another commiter

Tags: git

**Is there a way to assume ownership of long buried changes that were squashed onto the main branch, instead of merged?**

[image]
*In the picture, green branch from Green and Orange authors was squashed onto main by Blue author, resulting in obfuscated ownersip.*

We have a main branch (blue) which is controlled only by the repo owner (blue dots).
Green and Orange authors create feature branches that are then added to the main, however, former practice was to squash everything to "make the main clean". We have since abandoned this and do normal merges, rebases or fast-forwards, however, there are still many changes in the repo with the (incorrect) Blue author causing difficulties in communication and misunderstandings when working with the old code.

Unfortunately this has happened weeks ago and many features were already added since.

The main branch is locked, but I guess I could make the required changes on an ad-hoc branch and then try to convince the owner to rewrite the history ¯\*(ツ)*/¯, but a non-invasive approach that only involves merges, resets, etc. would be preferable.

---

I tried some combo of reverts, resets and cherry-picks on top of main, which helped me fix the ownership of those particular changes, but I am unable to re-introduce the main back on top of this branch, because an attempt to merge from main gives "already up to date", which makes sense since main was a base for this.

What can I do?

Comment: What "difficulties in communication and misunderstandings" are you referring to? Not knowing who actually contributed a change? (Not that it helps you now, but this is why commits have separate `Author` and `Commit` fields to distiniguish between who wrote the code and who committed it to the repository.)

Comment: I dislike squash merge, as it is not a merge, and does not in my opinion actually make anything "cleaner". So I'm with you. But I don't understand what difficulty is being caused here. If you did squash merges in GitHub, let's say, by way of a PR, there is still a connection with the PR built into the squash merge message. So there isn't really a problem; the original commits were never lost, since PRs live forever. I think you should just stop worrying about "ownership" and "author", don't try to modify `main` in some artificial way, and move on.

Comment: Being able to see WHEN was WHICH change introduced by WHO helps establish the context and reasoning behind the feature, which in return enables to make better use of it or improve it. The commit messages also sometimes bring value.
This all is especially useful when the feature is rather complex.
Having to go through the original PR, not seeing the "git blame" annotations inline or being able to traverse the changes within IDE is a major PITA.

Comment: You can use `git notes` to annotate existing commits with the information that should have gone in the commit originally. Not sure if that will suffice for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technical way to rewrite your history :

1. run :

```
git replace --graft <squash merge commit> <parent1> <parent2>
```

This will make your local clone behave as if there was an actual merge commit instead of the squash merge.

2. run :

```
git filter-repo --force
```

To make the replacements permanent.

---

If you can afford to rewrite the repo's history, you may try to have the maintainer update it.

Another possibility it to :

- create locally a branch with squash merges replaced with actual merges eg : `master-with-merges`)
- push this branch on the remote so that everyone can access it
- add a script which runs the correct `git replace` command so that everyone can have a local view of the "actual" merges

Comment: I am in awe and absolutely speechless.  Git is awesome. period.

Comment: So anyway, after running `git filter-repo --force` I am left with hundreds of replace refs (`git replace -l`), can I assume they are obsolete and delete them? The changes should be permanent, right? Meaning, when I push to a remote and somebody clones it, they get exactly what I have - not needing any replace ref any more?

Comment: Interesting, when I have a cherry-picked commit that references the original commit hash in its message I get diverging histories for these two scenarios: the original commit is 1) reachable, 2) unreachable. That means that when two people perform the `filter-repo`, but only one of them has the original commit, the result is disaster. /edit: Solution is to disable message updates: `--preserve-commit-hashes`. More [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/386).